# How to build a single page app with polymer 1.0?

Tags: angularjs, polymer

I didn't see any guide on the website. Can we use polymer with angular.js?
Others options?

Answer (score 1):

We are currently investigating the use of Polymer alongside Angular and this article gives a demonstration on how it can be achieved:

[Using Polymer WebComponents with Angular.js](http://jcrowther.io/2015/05/26/using-polymer-webcomponents-with-angular-js/)

The author does conclude by saying not to mix the two worlds, but he admits that is just an opinion.

Binding values from Angular to Polymer seems to work well. The issue is controlling the flow of information out of Polymer back into Angular.

This directive helps with this:

[angular-bind-polymer](https://github.com/eee-c/angular-bind-polymer)

There are a couple of things I don't quite like with this:

1. You have to decorate your elements with the directive.
2. You have to enable reflectToAttribute in your Polymer element, which if it is a large javascript object for example could be ugly.

Having said all that it works, so if you think it will work for you then evaluate it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start with the aptly named [Polymer Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/).

As for use with Angular, Polymer elements work well with Angular 2.0, currently in Alpha.